# how do you fix a modal window?

Tags: reactjs

My modal window closes with any clicking. But it should close only when you click past the modal window. What am I doing wrong?
I did 'overlay' when I clicked on which window it should close. Now I can't even write anything in the form.

Can you help me, please? I'm still a newbie.

This is what I was able to write myself.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {isShow: false};
        this.showHidePopup = this.showHidePopup.bind(this);
    }

    showHidePopup(){
        let isShow = this.state.isShow;
        this.setState({isShow: !isShow});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <li onClick={this.showHidePopup} className="sign-in">sign up</li>
                    {this.state.isShow ? <Authorisation /> : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    afterClick:{display:'none'},
    beforeClick:{display:'block'}
}

class Authorisation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isClickedOutside: false
        }
        this.handleClickBackground = this.handleClickBackground.bind(this);
    }

    handleClickBackground = () => {
        this.setState( {isClickedOutside: !this.state.isClickedOutside})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'overlay'} onClick={this.handleClickBackground} style={this.state.isClickedOutside ? styles.afterClick : styles.beforeClick} >
                <div className="login-form">
                    <p className="enter">Вход</p>
                    <button className="vk">Вконтакте</button>
                    <div className="info-login">
                        <input required="required" type='email' placeholder="Почта"/>
                        <input required="required" type="password" placeholder="Пароль"/>
                        <a className="iForgotPassword" href="/#">забыли пароль?</a>
                    </div>
                    <button className="enter-button">Войти</button>
                    <div className="registration">Зарегистрироваться</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #999;
}

.login-form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:#777;
  z-index:3;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your implementation of `handleClickBackground` to the following:-

```
handleClickBackground = (e) => {
    if(e.target.className==='overlay')
    {
        this.setState( {isClickedOutside: !this.state.isClickedOutside})
    }
    }
```

This ensures that your `target` is the only one responsible for setting the state. When you were clicking on Login form, it also triggers a `click` event which bubbles up to the overlay and triggers it's `onClick`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which element is being clicked with associated `class`

```js
 isOutside = (element) => {
   return element.classList.contains("overlay");
 }

 handleClickBackground = (event) => {
  const element = event.target;

  if(isOutside(element)) { // or any other logic 
    this.setState( {isClickedOutside: !this.state.isClickedOutside})    
  }

 }
```

Or if you like `refs`

```
<div ref={this.overlayRef} className={'overlay'} onClick={this.handleClickBackground} style={this.state.isClickedOutside ? styles.afterClick : styles.beforeClick} >
```

```js
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          isClickedOutside: false
      }
      this.handleClickBackground = this.handleClickBackground.bind(this);
      this.overlayRef = React.createRef();
  }

 isOutside = (element) => {
   return element === this.overlayRef.current;
 }

 handleClickBackground = (event) => {
  const element = event.target;

  if(isOutside(element)) { // or any other logic 
    this.setState( {isClickedOutside: !this.state.isClickedOutside})    
  }
```